# How to Allow Google fonts in IdentityServer4

Tags: security, identityserver4, google-fonts

To use Google fonts in IdentityServer3, the following Content-Security-Policy never worked:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" 
      content=" style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://fonts.googleapis.com;
                font-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://fonts.gstatic.com data:">
```

Instead we configured the CspOptions in the idsrvApp.UseIdentityServer constructor which did work:

```
CspOptions = new CspOptions {
    FontSrc = "https://fonts.gstatic.com",
    StyleSrc = "https://fonts.googleapis.com",
    Enabled = true
}
```

How can we configure CspOptions in IdentityServer4?  I'm having trouble finding it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For anyone else who gets stuck, the SecurityHeadersAttribute.cs file that comes with the IdentityServer4 quickstart files needs to be modified. Appending the following lines fixed it:

```
var csp = "default-src 'self'; object-src 'none'; frame-ancestors 'none'; sandbox allow-forms allow-same-origin allow-scripts; base-uri 'self';";

// These two lines enable google fonts
csp += "font-src 'self' https://fonts.gstatic.com;";
csp += "style-src 'self' https://fonts.googleapis.com;";
```

The file is located in quickstart/SecurityHeadersAttribute.cs

Comment: Thanks i was looking for a way to add 3rd party scripts-src to identityServer4 base app and with your comment i figured it out thanks that was helpful

Comment: Works with .NET 5 & IdentityServer4, thanks!